# Failure to create Genesis Block (Hyperledger fabric)

Tags: docker, unix, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This is my first post on Stackoverflow. Please bear with me... 
I am new to basically everything around hyperledger-fabric. 
While trying to follow the "Writing Your First Application Tutorial" i am unable to generate the genesis block.

I am running:

> windows 10
>
> Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302
>
> docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b2
>
> npm 6.1.2
>
> node.js v12.1
>
> python 2.7

I used the curl commands given in the instructions.

When i run
`./startFabric.sh javascript`
at first everything is going ok. I am getting some warnings but starting the Channel seems to work fine. 
In the next few lines however i am getting an error.

`Generate CCP files for Org1 and Org2
/c/Users/Jonathan/Hyperledger_Fabric/fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen
Generating Orderer Genesis block 
CONSENSUS_TYPE=solo
+ '[' solo == solo ']'
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
2019-11-25 10:35:01.676 CET [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2019-11-25 10:35:01.677 CET [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> PANI 002 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
2019-11-25 10:35:01.679 CET [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 003 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
panic: Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type "" [recovered]
        panic: Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""`

It seems that the configuration is missing/not the right "type". 
I googled my error and came up with people having similar/the same issue but i havent been able to solve my issue by following the advice they were given (hence why i am here). 
Similar posts i found:

- https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3467
- [Error cryptogen tool in Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685611/error-cryptogen-tool-in-hyperledger-fabric)

The people responding to the posts above generally seem to think its an issue regarding the path to the config file which apparently can be fixed with

```
FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
```

But that hasnt worked for me.

Full Console Output: 
https://pastebin.com/CHxjZ1Uq

Answer (score 0):

Look at the warning at the start: you are missing some prerequisites.

First, use the generate script to generate the crypto-config and artifacts folder.
Once you got your certificates you can start fabric.

You should have a generte.sh script or something like that.
Essentially it runs the certificate generation for your network using cryptogen.

The code is something like this:

```
  which cryptogen
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "cryptogen tool not found. exiting"
    exit 1
  fi

  if [ -d "crypto-config" ]; then
    rm -Rf crypto-config
  fi

  set -x
  cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

Once you generated the certificates, you can now generate the genesis block with something like:

```
 which configtxgen

 if [ -d "config" ]; then
    rm -Rf config
  fi
  mkdir config

  configtxgen -profile OneOrgOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block
  configtxgen -profile OneOrgChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
  configtxgen -profile OneOrgChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/${MSP_NAME}anchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg $MSP_NAME
```

Obviously replacing with your names and variables.